# Finding best local axis system of a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, algorithms

I’m looking for a way to find the best axis system for a set of points and its tessellation – triangles, linking points to each others. The idea is that I’d like to orient a mesh using that axis system so that it matches the $\mathbb{R}^3$ axis system.

I looked into PCA (Principal Component Analysis), but it would eventually give me a nice variance over the points, yet no *optimal* local axis. I’m looking for algorithms / methods to do that.

Comment: First you have to define what you mean by words like "best" and "optimal"

Comment: I mean, with an orientation that we can appreciate. If you take a glass, you expect its foot to be at origin and its symmetric axis should be aligned with Y+. If you take a car, you expect it to presented to you as it was on road. If you take a cube, you expect it to be aligned with the canonical coord system. And so on. I don’t have any mathematics words to define that.

Comment: You can find the axis of symmetry of the glass. But there is no way for any algorithm to know that this should aligned with +Y (versus -Y or +Z). Similarly, you can find the plane of symmetry of a car, but no algorithm can know that the wheels are supposed to go on the bottom and the roof on the top. For finding symmetry, PCA is a good start.

Comment: Ok so basically, if the model admits symmetry, I can make it through. If it’s an arbitrary mesh, I’m screwed. Right? I guess I could implement some kind of minimisation by freezing two rotations out of three and check when the model is correctly implemented, and then free the first rotation and freeze the first and third and repeat…

Comment: You're screwed until you can develop a mathematical definition of "best" that you can use in some sort of optimization algorithm.

Comment: Hm, yeah, ok. I’ll need to think of that then. Thank you.